# Unity canvas scaler hiding animations in high resolution display

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I instantiate the following gameObject, which contains an Animator with the mode "always animate" on, the animation goes for 340ms, after that time I destroy the gameObject.

The gameObject Inspector properties:
[image]

I instantiate it using the following code:

```
instancia = (Instantiate(cardAnimation, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject).GetComponent<Image>();
instancia.rectTransform.SetParent(transform);
StartCoroutine(KillOnAnimationEnd());
```

Here is the Coroutine:

```
private IEnumerator KillOnAnimationEnd()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.34f);
    DestroyImmediate(instancia);
}
```

Here is how the animation looks like when simulating in Unity (PC-Windows):
[image]

But on android after I open the chest it waits 340ms with nothing happening and then show the information above, does this have something to do with the plataform or is some unity or perhaps code related issue?

NOTE: I also have another animation in another scene that is just a already instantiated gameObject in the Hierarchy with always animated on and it works on Android.

--EDIT--
So I have ran the newest version of the app in a emulator which is almost about 1080x480 and the animation showed just as the PC, also running on a 720p smartphone did the job, the only problem I'm still having is with my QuadHD resolution from Galaxy S6, everything else shows but the animation, I have even tried making the animation run without any script so it runs in a loop, but it doesn't show up in galaxy screen.

Given the news about the issue I think this might change a little bit the perspective of answers and perhaps help someone else solve the same problem in the future.

Comment: Are you working for Supercell?

Comment: Nope haha, this is actually a Chest Simulator i've made, just for fun.

Comment: Are you sure you are allowed to use their graphics?

Comment: Im not charging anyone for anything, i'm giving them the credits for everything, this is nothing different than a wikia page, both contains images from the game, information of its content and both are free, I don't understand why wikia is allowed but an app not :x

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured out the problem, its something to do with "rotation" in animations using Unity3D in 2D mode, gonna be reporting it form Unity so it is fixed.

**The solution**: Animate your UI only using scale/position, if used rotation it will not show on high resolution display.

Answer (score -1):

I am pretty sure your `WaitForSeconds(0.34f)` is not working properly because there is no thing such as `yield` keyword in Java. I recommend you to use a [invoke](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) method instead to call your method that destroys your GameObject.

Comment: Ahhhh, I really wanted this to be the reason, but just tried, it worked on PC but android still the same.

Comment: Are you using canvas scale or unity remote? Maybe it is just something related to the screen size of your phone

Comment: Canvas Scale from Unity 5.0, my phone is Quad HD (Galaxy S6)